# vsprintf_s() does not work when va_list has length set by local variable

Tags: c, visual-c++

I have a utility C function that works correctly:

```
void UtilDisplayMessage(char* strCaption, char* strMessageFormat, int iArgCount, ...)
{
    // Initialize the variable arg list
    va_list lstArgs;
    va_start(lstArgs, iArgCount);

    // Format the message
    vsprintf_s(g_strMessage, UTIL_DEF_MESSAGE_SIZE, strMessageFormat, lstArgs);

    // Destroy the variable arg list
    va_end(lstArgs);

    // Use formatted string here...
}
```

But I would like to remove the 'iArgCount' parameter and so I've made a test function that looks like this:

```
void UtilDisplayMessageEasy(char* strCaption, char* strMessageFormat, ...)
{
    // Initialize the variable arg list
    va_list lstArgs;

    int iParamCount = 1;
    va_start(lstArgs, iParamCount);

    // Format the message
    vsprintf_s(g_strMessage, UTIL_DEF_MESSAGE_SIZE, strMessageFormat, lstArgs);

    // Destroy the variable arg list
    va_end(lstArgs);

    // Use formatted string here...
}
```

But I get bogus results if I pass in an integer value with this call:

```
UtilDisplayMessageEasy("TEST", "The value is %i.", 1);
```

And I get an Access Violation Exception when I pass in a string with this call:

```
UtilDisplayMessageEasy("TEST", "This is only a %s.", "TEST");
```

Yet, it works fine if I call my original function like so:

```
UtilDisplayMessage("TEST", "This is only a %s.", 1, "TEST");
```

Is there really such a fundamental difference on whether I pass in an argument parameter or a local parameter into va_start()?

Also I'm aware that variable parameters are not very safe and should used with care, but surely something this innocuous shouldn't set the alarms blaring.

Thank you for any input you might have regarding this issue.

Comment: In `UtilDisplayMessageEasy` change `va_start(lstArgs, iParamCount);`  to `va_start(lstArgs, strMessageFormat);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second argument to `va_start` needs to be the LAST PARAMETER before the `...` in the function declaration.  So it needs to be `iArgCount` in the first case and `strMessageFormat` in the second case.  Using anything else there in the second argument (such as a local variable) gives you undefined behavior -- hopefully the compiler will give you an error, but it might just accept it silently and do something random.

Comment: Wow! You think I would have seen that in the docs. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

the va_list variable is used to derive the starting address of ... from the argument just before it. it is a requirement. 
you can't use a local, you might want to do

```
va_start(lstArgs, strMessageFormat);
```

instead.